# i am creating a to do list model (TodoModel) in django, and I want to display data of the logged in user only, but I am getting the data of all users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

i want to display the data of logged in user only, but im getting data of all users .i.e i want to display task, deadline and note of logged in user only in my case. **admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin                                                                  
from .models import TodoModel                                            
admin.site.register(TodoModel)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import TodoModel
class TodoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = TodoModel
    widgets = {
        'task': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':21}),
        'Note': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':21}),
        }
    fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
class TodoModel(models.Model):
task = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
deadline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Note = models.TextField(max_length=50)
def __str__(self):
    return self.task
```

**views.py**:

```
def showtask(request):
data = TodoModel.objects.all()
return render(request, "showtask.html",{"data":data})
```

**showtask html file:**

```
<table border="2">
        <tr>
    <th>Tasks</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Note</th>
```

{% for d in data%}

```
    <tr>
            <td> {{ d.task }} </td>
            <td> {{ d.deadline }} </td>
            <td> {{ d.Note }} </td>
    </tr>

{% empty %}
    <tr>
            <td> no data found </td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Here i'm trying to get data(task,deadline and note) for only the logged in user, but instead im getting the data of all the users. It will be a great help if someone help me with this, i'm just a django begineer.

Comment: You need to store the user that created each todo by adding a `ForeignKey` to `TodoModel` and storing currently logged in user when creating

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to add a relation between your `TodoModel` and the `User` model.

In the `models.py` import `User` model like this `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. After that add a `user` field into `TodoModel` like this `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`. Make and apply migration. After that, all `TodoModel` objects will be linked to the user.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TodoModel(models.Model):
    task = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    deadline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Note = models.TextField(max_length=50) # btw, make this attribute lowercase
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

Now in the `views.py` you can filter `TodoModel` using current user. `request` has user linked to it. That means you can use this object in the filter `data = TodoModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

And don't forget to add the `login_required` decorator to your view, because you will get an error on an anonymous request.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def showtask(request):
    data = TodoModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "showtask.html",{"data":data})
```

Comment: thankyou, i made the changes as said by yourself , but after doing the required changes im getting an error **OperationalError at /showtask
no such column: sqrapp_todomodel.user_id** while rendering my template. the code for showtask.html template file is in my posted question.

Comment: After changing the model code you should make and apply migrations by executing 2 commands at the root of your project:
python manage.py makemigrations - this command will create a new migration file
python manage.py migrate - apply migrations to the database
These 2 commands will create the required column in the database so it will match your code. Please read about migrations in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: thankyou very much it worked wonders! but when i go to add task page I get a drop down menu of all the users and then i need to select which user will add task, i want to avoid that and I want only the logged in user to add task and not any other users.please help me with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy solution for this. You will need to create a dedicated page with a form (or endpoint if you want to use API) for the task creation. In the dedicated view, you will be able to get user object from the incoming request and link it to a new task.